# Ghost admin for two websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, ghost

I have a Ghost blog (0.7.4). In my configuration file I set the *url* to http://myurl.com. When I access the admin panel through http://myurl.com/ghost I have access to the panel, but if I use http://www.myurl.com/ghost it returns an error that I'm not allowed to access the admin panel through that address. Is there any way to make ghost accepts more than one value in *url*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ghost config currently only seems to accept a single String value for the URL (most likely because it needs to have a single URL to construct links from): [config/index.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/config/index.js#L360-L368)

Depending on your needs, you could simply 301 redirect all traffic from *www.myurl.com* to *myurl.com*.

If you wanted to try and implement yourself you'd need to be careful that you don't introduce side-effects elsewhere. The [url.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/config/url.js) file for example expects a single String value in various places. You could edit `config/index.js` to expect an `Array` or a `RegExp` but you'd need to make sure there's always a single "correct" URL elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a "right" way to do it in ghost or may I just hack?

Comment: Don't think you can do it in Ghost. I would perform the redirect as duncanhall mentions. Use something like nginx to proxy your requests through.

Answer (score 1):

Change you Nginx or HAProxy running in front of the Ghost blog to 301 redirect to the url without www.

Comment: I'm using none of these, yet.

Comment: If you are self hosting you should as hosting of Node.js directly isn't suggested because of SSL. The SSL support is there but very slow compared to using these as well as for this use case and a little extra security.